# NVD3 - Determine if tooltip is flipped

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3 1.8 for charting and I've implemented a custom tooltip because our visual design department didn't like the one that the library came with.  I've been able to implement most of the design, but I have one problem:

[image: The tooltip arrow needs to flip]

The arrow on the tooltip needs to point to the guideline whether it's on the right or the left.  I made this arrow using CSS and I can easily add a class to move it to the other side, but the problem is figuring out *when* to apply the class.  When the user's mouse gets too close to the right side of the screen, the `transform: translation()` value of the tooltip is changed so that it appears to the left side of the mouse rather than the right.

This is done based on the width if the tooltip, NOT a static distance from the right edge of the screen (I know this because my tooltip dynamically resizes based on its contents, and a tooltip further to the left can sometimes be flipped left by having larger number values).  I don't know how to access the "flip" information programmatically, as it seems to make this check after the tooltip is already rendered.  How can I get around this conundrum?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to just decide that if the guideline is on the right side of the screen then make the tooltip go to the left, and if it's on the left side make the tooltip go to the right?

You could perform a calculation where you just take the width / 2.  This is what I do whenever I have a tooltip.  I also move the tooltip below the cursor when it's on the upper portion of the page and move the tooltip above the cursor when it's on the bottom portion of the page

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this calculation is already done by NVD3.  This did give me the idea of adding a `margin-right` or negative `margin-left` to trick it into always putting it on the left, but this made the CSS of the rest of the tooltip look strange =/